# Prepared statements and how they affect queries

Tags: php, mysqli, prepared-statement

In an effort to make my scripts more secure, I have started using prepared statements to prevent mysql injection. This script inserts the data just fine, but getting the last inserted id (based on auto incrementation in the database) now returns 0 when it should return the correct id number.

This part inserts just fine.

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO users (userName) VALUES (?)");
$stmt->bind_param("s", $_SESSION['username']);
$stmt->execute();
```

This is where I am having problems. I am trying to get the last inserted ID of the user and it is returning 0.

```
// Get the last inserted ID for the users ID
$query = "SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID()";
$result = mysql_query($query);
if ($result) {
    $nrows = mysql_num_rows($result);
    $row = mysql_fetch_row($result);
    $userId = $row[0];
}
```

This was working when I had my script before starting on Prepared Statements. The only thing I changed was adding the Prepared Statement to insert the data and my db connection is as follows:

```
$conn = new mysqli($server, $user, $password, $database) or die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
```

I am a noob with php so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

You may have a fundamental misunderstanding: When you switch to `mysqli`, your `mysql_*` functions will no longer use the same connection.

`LAST_INSERT_ID()` works on a per-connection basis.

You will have to make that query using the same library/connection as the main query, or as @zerkms points out, use [`$conn->insert_id`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.insert-id.php).

Comment: This answer will be complete with this line `$conn->insert_id`

Comment: There is no point in using a query to fetch the last insert id when you have API functions to do the same.

Comment: Or if he wants to keep on using PDO, then it's `$pdo_con->lastInsertId()` - http://de.php.net/manual/en/pdo.lastinsertid.php (In hindsight: he does not use PDO. Just implying he should. mysqli is an intermediate API.)

Comment: @vanneto usually yes, but note that the API functions and LAST_INSERT_ID() sometimes have subtle differences, at least in the mysql_* library: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mysql-insert-id.html

Comment: @Pekka and those who have also contributed. Thank you for your responses, they have been very helpful. I will now keep my fingers crossed that I can get this to work. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

[mysqli_insert_id()](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.insert-id.php).

Comment: Thank you. I have searched around but have been unsuccessful. Do you know if mysqli_insert_id() returns the last inserted row in the database as a whole, or is it per session? In the event that multiple users are inserting, I'd like to retrieve the last inserted ID of the user who made the insert.

Comment: @Jason, it's the last query for the `mysqli` object.